# Appending data to CSV repeatedly

Tags: python, csv, append, export-to-csv

I have a list of values that I am trying to append to a csv file every time my program runs but my code only appends once and never again. What am I doing wrong here.

```
import random
import csv
import numpy as np
from csv import writer

randomlist = []
for i in range (0,5):
    n = random.randint(1,30)
    randomlist.append(n)
print(randomlist)

np.savetxt("test.csv",  
           randomlist,
           fmt ='% s') 

def append_list_as_row(file_name, list_of_elem):
       with open(file_name, 'a+', newline='') as file:
                csv_writer = writer(file)
                csv_writer.writerow(list_of_elem)      

append_list_as_row('test.csv',randomlist)
```

Answer (score 2):

When you call `np.savetxt("test.csv", randomlist, fmt ='% s')`, this method overrides `test.csv`, so just don't call it, you can do something like:

```py
from csv import writer
import numpy as np 
import random
import csv


def main():
  randomlist = []
  for i in range (0,5):
    n = random.randint(1,30)
    randomlist.append(n)
  print(randomlist)

  # np.savetxt("test.csv", randomlist, fmt ='% s') 
  append_list_as_row('test.csv', randomlist)

def append_list_as_row(file_name, list_of_elem):
  with open(file_name, 'a+', newline='') as file:
    csv_writer = writer(file)
    csv_writer.writerow(list_of_elem)   


if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you're saving a new `"test.csv"` file everytime you run the code with the function `np.savetxt`.

Try separating this part of the code:

```py
np.savetxt("test.csv",  
           randomlist,
           fmt ='% s')
```

from the rest of the code,
let it run only once